# How to join and filter on OneToOne unidirectional from Root which does not know the other entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Given

```
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "foo_seq")
    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;
```

```
public class FooDetailsEntity  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "foo_details_seq")
    @Column(name = "foo_details_id", updatable = false)
    private long id;

  
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FooType type;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_foo_id", referencedColumnName = "foo_id")
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private FooEntity owningFoo;

    
    public enum FooType {
        BIG,
        SMALL
    }
```

What I am now trying to implement:
Get all `Foo` which are not of `Set<FooType>`

I need to implement it using the criteria api due to the fact that we do some other filtering on other properties which are left out due to brevity.

What I've tried and does not work at all:

```
  private List<FooEntity> getFoos(Root<FooEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<FooEntity> cq, Set<Predicate> predicatesToApply, CriteriaBuilder cb, Set<FooDetailsEntity.FooType> fooTypesToExclude) {
    final Set<Predicate> applicablePredicates = new HashSet<>(predicatesToApply);

    if (!fooTypesToExclude.isEmpty()) {
        log.debug("Excluding certain foo types.");

        Root<FooDetailsEntity> subRoot = cq.from(FooDetailsEntity.class);
        final Join<FooDetailsEntity, FooEntity> subJoin = subRoot.join(FooDetailsEntity_.owiningFoo);

        fooTypesToExclude
                .forEach(type ->  {
                    applicablePredicates.add(cb.and(cb.notEqual(subJoin.get(FooDetailsEntity.type), type)));
                });
    }

    cq.where(applicablePredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    TypedQuery<FooEntity> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    tq.setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, true);
    return tq.getResultList();
}
```

The result query should look like this:

```sql
select
        f.*
    from
        foo f
    left join foo_details fd on
        fd.fk_foo_id = f.foo_id
    where
        fd."type" not in('BIG', 'SMALL')
```

Comment: What you've got and seems pretty straight forward and similar to JPQL: "Select <something> from FooDetailsEntity details join details.owningFoo foo where .." up to the where clause, is that working as you want and expect? It isn't clear what you are attempting with applicablePredicates or how they are added to the query itself, so you may want to go into more details, and possibly remove the cb.and as I don't see it adding anything. Seems like you want "where foo.type not in (:types)". I don't see the need to go through the fooTypesToExclude list and add individual clauses to the query

Comment: I'm trying to fetch all `Foo`entities which are not of `FooType` XY. The `FooType` to exclude are inside the `fooTypesToExclude` set. The main problem is that `Foo`does not know anything about `FooDetails`and only `FooDetails` knows to which `Foo` it belongs. I've updated my question to provide more details

Comment: The JPQL is exactly how you need to build your criteria query. "Select foo from FooDetailsEntity details join details.owningFoo foo where details.type not in :types". You've got the join fine in your code, it is your applicablePredicates.add statement that is likely not working for you - but we can't tell as you haven't described how it isn't working. There is no need to build a details.type != :param1 clause in a loop when you can pass the collection of values, and JPA does the join for you through the Details->Foo relationship.

Comment: But it is not working the way I'm trying it `No explicit selection and an implicit one could not be determined` - I am doing something wrong but currently I don't know what

Comment: Seems you haven't set the criteriaQuery.select yet - see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html . If you need more help, you haven't shown much code around your query, so it is/was assumed you would have setup the selection before passing in the root and a criteria query; show it all.